# How do I address the checkout button?

Tags: commerce, forms

I need to add a custom function to the *Confirm Order* button on a Commerce Checkout form. I can't figure out how to call it. The button ID is *#edit-continue* and its displayed text is *Confirm Order*. I thought this would show up in the `$form[submit]` array, but that array is empty. So I checked `$form['buttons']['continue']['#submit']`, which  seems to be where Drupal Commerce stores the submit functions.

I created a module and two functions.

```php
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id){ 
   drupal_set_message('ALTERING CHECKING OUT! THIS WORKS' . $form_id);   
   $form['buttons']['continue']['#value'] = 'Send Me A Quote!';
   $form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_submit';       

function MYMODULE_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  die('Triggered submit');
}
```

`drupal_set_message()` shows the message, but the submit function isn't invoked, and the text in the button is not altered. So clearly, the problem is that I am not targeting the button properly. How do I "address" that button?

To make it clearer, I need to overload that button, not replace the commerce checkout functionality.

PS: I have no access to the console or Devel. So I'm limited to debugging with `var_dump().`

Comment: So what you're trying to achieve with your custom php? Maybe you should try Rules ?

Answer (score 1):

Your changes to $form here are lost because you are passing by value.  Pass by reference using `&$form` instead:

```
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
```

Comment: Also have a look at this for more information on passing variables as references in PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Since `$form` is an array, the hook needs to define its parameter as `&$form`. If `$form` were an object, using `$form` as parameter would let the changes be passed to the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using hook form alter
so do a dpm($form) before adding the custom function to the submit handler and then do dpm($form) again after adding your custom handler and see if it shows your custom handler over there or not. dpm() will work if you have devel module installed otherwise do a var_dump() instead of dpm(), debugging the code should take you to the answer.

Comment: I don't have Devel installed. I did a var_dump() on the $form array and the 'Confirm' button is in the ['buttons'] section. I added this above. Any ideas?

Comment: Also... another possible noob question: why doesn't the #ID attribute of the button match anything in the $form array?

Answer (score 0):

Based solely on the code you gave above, you've got at least one glaring issue. This code is okay:

```
function MYMODULE_form_commerce_checkout_form_checkout_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id){ 
   drupal_set_message('ALTERING CHECKING OUT! THIS WORKS' . $form_id);   
   $form['buttons']['continue']['#value'] = 'Send Me A Quote!';
   $form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][] = 'MYMODULE_submit';
```

However, in this block:

```
function MYMODULE_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  die('Triggered submit');
}
```

`MYMODULE_submit_function` should actually be the same as the handler you added in the form alter (i.e. `MYMODULE_submit` without the `_function`).

It's looking for that exact function name and won't add anything else to it like it does with the other form submit handlers that are called in `drupal_get_form()`.

Comment: `$form`, which is an array, isn't passed by reference. Any change in `$form` is local to the function. That is why the code shown from the OP doesn't work.